# Theme for small screen?

Tags: unity, themes

I'm running the latest (15.x) vanilla Ubuntu on an old laptop, Thinkpad x60. It's running pretty smoothly with an SSD and 4G of RAM. But the screen is pretty small (1024x768). So any UI bells and whistles are just taking up the screen real estate and I want to minimize them. I have already set the UI font size to 9. But I wonder if it's possible to minimize button borders and such. I'm also open to other flavors of Ubuntu if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can scale back menus in Settings -> Display.  There is a slider that is set to 1.00 by default.  This slider controls the relative size of menus and UI elements.  This may greatly help your problem.

Also, you might want to consider replacing the LCD with a higher-res screen.  I'm pretty sure that is an upgradable option.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it's a 10 year old laptop :). I threw in an SSD and some RAM just because I had them around. I doubt it's worth to buy a new LCD for it.

Comment: Probably not, but if you can always transfer the SSD (probably not the RAM) to a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu allows you to choose more compact LXDE window decoration for smaller screens, or screens with lower resolution.

Answer (score 0):

XFCE, Gnome 2, MATE and others have settings to change the style of the window borders & buttons. If the settings aren't easily found, may need a 3rd party program to do some tweaks, maybe [Ubuntu Tweak](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTweak) (but I've read it can make some potentially unsafe "tweaks", so caution is required. And a good backup of your important data, as always right ;-)

I don't want to recommend a whole different Desktop or WM if you're happy with regular Ubuntu (Unity?)...

In XFCE it's under Settings -> Window Manager -> Style (also Settings -> Appearance is good too).

Comment: Thanks. I tried xubuntu livecd yesterday and it was pretty good. I may go with it. Have briefly used xfce about 10 years ago and wasn't very impressed back then.

Comment: XFCE used to be almost the same as Gnome (2), I checked it out back then too and figured "why bother, same as Gnome." Now that Gnome 3  took a different road, I still like the XFCE/Gnome 2 style. I read a few months ago Debian might go with XFCE as their default desktop, wonder if they did?